# Flutter: OnScreen keyboard not opening when TextView is focused

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-authentication, textview

I'm trying to create a simple login and signup screen for an app using Firebase Authentication (email/password). When testing on both physical device and emulator, the onscreen keyboard doesn't pop up, when the TextView is focused. On occasion, another screen which I can't identify pops up soon after running for a split second, but not every time.

It worked once after I'd realized I'd forgotten to import `async` and it seemed to work. After resuming working on it later, suddenly the keyboard wasn't opening again. I have tried removing pretty much all my code and leaving only the UI, but the on-screen keyboard didn't show.

#### Code

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(title: 'Login Test', home: LoginScreen()));

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
    TextEditingController _uname = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController _pword = TextEditingController();

    Future<FirebaseUser> _handleSignIn(var context, String email, String password) async{
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog(
            content: new Text("Loading...")
        );
        showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) => dialog);
        _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password).then((FirebaseUser user) {
            print("success");
        }).catchError((e) => print(e));
        Navigator.pop(context);
        return _auth.currentUser;
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            Container loginScreen;
            TextField username = TextField(controller: _uname, decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Email",), keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress, );
            TextField password = TextField(controller: _pword, decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Password",), keyboardType: TextInputType.text, obscureText: true,);
            RaisedButton login = RaisedButton(child: Text("Login"),
                onPressed: (){ _handleSignIn(context, _uname.text.toString(), _pword.text.toString()); }
            );
            loginScreen = Container(child: Column(children: [username, password, login]), padding: EdgeInsets.all(16));
            return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: "Login Screen"), body: loginScreen); 
    }
}
```

Flutter Doctor Output:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.437], locale en-US)
• Flutter version 1.0.0 at C:\flutter
• Framework revision 5391447fae (5 months ago), 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
• Engine revision 7375a0f414
• Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\laury\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
• Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin version 34.0.2
• Dart plugin version 183.5901
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.30.2)
• VS Code at C:\Users\laury\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 2.22.3

[√] Connected device (1 available)
• moto g 7 • ZY225F2VS7 • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)

• No issues found!
```

According to most of the documentation I've read, the keyboard should open when the **TextView** is focused/selected, but it isn't opening for a reason I can't seem to pin.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Does it show any warnings or errors?

Comment: It works fine for me when running it to an Android emulator. If you are running it on an iOS emulator, the keyboard doesn't show by default so therefore you need to press ⌘K for it to show.

Comment: @JideGuruTheProgrammer The only warning I get is that registerResGenerating Task is deprecated.

Comment: can you paste your `flutter doctor` above, so people can be able to help you better.

Comment: You can try updating flutter, it might help

Comment: @JideGuruTheProgrammer, Updating Flutter fixed it.

Comment: Glad it's fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a `bug` in some old versions of `Flutter`. Performing `flutter upgrade` will fix it.

This [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading) contains information on how to upgrade flutter